# Python pandas employee heirarchy recursive function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df

```
Employee Id    Manager ID
1                3
2                1
3                4
4                NULL
5                NULL
6                7
7                5  and so on
```

So, 4 and 5 emp id are CXOs. Heirarchies expected output:(manager to employees under him)

```
Mgr Employees
1  2
2  None
3  1,2
4  3,1,2
5  7,6
6  None
7  6
```

e.g. 4 is the manager of 3(level 1), 3 is the manager of 1 (level 2) and 1 is the manager of 2(level 3).

Can anyone help. I know it using SQL but want solution in pandas only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) to create a connected `DiGraph` having source as `Manager ID` and target as `Employee Id`, then using [`nx.descendants`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html) inside a list comprehension we can get all the nodes reachable from source:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df, 'Manager ID', 'Employee Id', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

s = [','.join(map(str, nx.descendants(G, i))) for i in df['Employee Id']]
d = pd.DataFrame({'Manager': df['Employee Id'].tolist(), 'Employee': s}).replace('', np.nan)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

   Manager Employee
0        1        2
1        2      NaN
2        3      1,2
3        4    1,2,3
4        5      6,7
5        6      NaN
6        7        6
```

Answer (score 1):

Good straight forward recursion... can be used to get mgrs or employees

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Employee Id    Manager ID
1                3
2                1
3                4
4                NULL
5                NULL
6                7
7                5"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

def walk(df, id, f, r, prev=pd.Series(dtype="int64")):
    mgr = df.loc[df[f]==id,][r]
    if not mgr.isna().all():
        prev = walk(df, mgr.tolist()[0], f, r, prev)
    return pd.concat([mgr, prev])


df = df.assign(
    mgrs=lambda x: x["Employee Id"].apply(lambda e: (walk(x, e, "Employee Id", "Manager ID")
                                                     .dropna().astype("int64").tolist())),
    emps=lambda x: x["Employee Id"].apply(lambda e: (walk(x, e, "Manager ID", "Employee Id")
                                                     .dropna().astype("int64").tolist())),
)
```

**output**

```
 Employee Id  Manager ID       mgrs       emps
           1         3.0     [3, 4]        [2]
           2         1.0  [1, 3, 4]         []
           3         4.0        [4]     [1, 2]
           4         NaN         []  [3, 1, 2]
           5         NaN         []     [7, 6]
           6         7.0     [7, 5]         []
           7         5.0        [5]        [6]
```